# How can make setting the default git branch permanent?

Tags: github, git-branch

I have a repo with three branches, "main", "qa" and "test".

Currently "main" is the default branch.

I have tried setting the default to "test" using this:

https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-branches-in-your-repository/changing-the-default-branch

Here is what I do:

Open repo - main is default

[image]

set test to default:

[image]

Logout, close browser, and reopen :

[image]

**NOTE: I NEED to keep all three branches**

How can I make setting the default branch permanent?

Comment: *But every time I go back to the repo, the default is set back to "test"* Where do you see the default being set back?

Comment: afaik, the default branch is set properly on GitHub by following the steps in the GitHub doc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/9840318/madhu-bhat - I have added more to the question

Comment: Okay, not sure why it is reverting. The default branch update works fine for me. Better contact GitHub support regarding it.